# SWIFT Syntax question with regards to a CLOSURE

Tags: swift, closures, core-graphics

maybe one could be so kind as to explain me this snippet

There is this nice tutorial about Core Graphics on [raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/410-core-graphics-tutorial-part-2-gradients-and-contexts). Unfortunately, the comments on that page are closed

The author declares

```swift
//Weekly sample data
var graphPoints = [4, 2, 6, 4, 5, 8, 3]
```

Note the "s" at the end of graphPoints. Then, to calculate the y coordinate for a chart with such figures, he uses graphPoint (without an "s" at the end) within a closure. Nevertheless the code runs just fine to my confusion.

```swift
// calculate the y point

let topBorder = Constants.topBorder
let bottomBorder = Constants.bottomBorder
let graphHeight = height - topBorder - bottomBorder
let maxValue = graphPoints.max()!
let columnYPoint = { (graphPoint: Int) -> CGFloat in
  let y = CGFloat(graphPoint) / CGFloat(maxValue) * graphHeight
  return graphHeight + topBorder - y // Flip the graph
}
```

And there is no further use of graphPoint in this project (that I am aware of, using "find"). So I wonder, how are graphPoints with an "s" linked to columnYPoint.

Though I currently have no idea how the y values flow into the closure, let me already extend my question: if my values are in a 2D array with the structure [[x1, x2], [y1, y2]], how would I pass only my y (or only my x) values into this closure?

Cheers!

UPDATE
This is how columnYPoint is used, afterwards, to draw the graph:

```swift
// draw the line graph

UIColor.white.setFill()
UIColor.white.setStroke()

// set up the points line
let graphPath = UIBezierPath()

// go to start of line
graphPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: columnXPoint(0), y: columnYPoint(graphPoints[0])))

// add points for each item in the graphPoints array
// at the correct (x, y) for the point
for i in 1..<graphPoints.count {
  let nextPoint = CGPoint(x: columnXPoint(i), y: columnYPoint(graphPoints[i]))
  graphPath.addLine(to: nextPoint)
}
graphPath.stroke()
```

Comment: Is `columnYPoint` used afterwards? If so, can you show how it's used?

Comment: I suggest to read [Closure Expression Syntax](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID95) again. `(graphPoint: Int)` is a closure parameter, and unrelated to `var graphPoints`.

Comment: You can read this great article also https://learnappmaking.com/closures-swift-how-to/

Comment: @Sweeper done -> Martin Mickael, I read https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html, however, I still did not really understand this example, because it does not apply on an existing array. But I will now look into Mickael's reference

Comment: I think, I got it. This closure does not apply to an array directly. Instead it stores a function in a variable which is then later applied to the graphPoints array - right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have correctly identified, this is a closure (put into the variable called `columnYPoint`, giving it a name):

```
let columnYPoint = { (graphPoint: Int) -> CGFloat in
  let y = CGFloat(graphPoint) / CGFloat(maxValue) * graphHeight
  return graphHeight + topBorder - y // Flip the graph
}
```

So really, it's like a function called `columnYPoint`:

```
func columnYPoint(_ graphPoint: Int) -> CGFloat {
    let y = CGFloat(graphPoint) / CGFloat(maxValue) * graphHeight
    return graphHeight + topBorder - y // Flip the graph
}
```

Why did the author wrote a closure and put it into a variable, instead of writing a function? I have no idea, because I can't read minds. It's a stylistic choice by the author.

And if you look at how it is being called, this function/closure calculates the Y coordinate of the bar, given the height of the bar, `graphPoint`. `graphPoint` is the parameter of the function, so of course it is not used in the rest of the code. As you can see from the caller:

```
graphPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: columnXPoint(0), y: columnYPoint(graphPoints[0])))
// and
let nextPoint = CGPoint(x: columnXPoint(i), y: columnYPoint(graphPoints[i]))
```

`columnYPoint` will be called for each element in `graphPoints`, so `graphPoint` will be each value in `graphPoints`. We need to calculate the coordinates of every bar, after all.

There seems to also be a `columnYPoint` closure mentioned earlier, which calculates the X coordinate given a given bar index. You can combine these two closures to give you a single closure that gives you a single `CGPoint`:

```
let margin = Constants.margin
let graphWidth = width - margin * 2 - 4
let topBorder = Constants.topBorder
let bottomBorder = Constants.bottomBorder
let graphHeight = height - topBorder - bottomBorder
let maxValue = graphPoints.max()!
let columnPoint = { (column: Int, graphPoint: Int) -> CGPoint in
    //Calculate the gap between points
    let spacing = graphWidth / CGFloat(self.graphPoints.count - 1)
    let x = CGFloat(column) * spacing + margin + 2
    let y = CGFloat(graphPoint) / CGFloat(maxValue) * graphHeight
    return CGPoint(x: x, y: graphHeight + topBorder - y) // Flip the graph
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sweeper! I was so focussed on array manipulation that I missed the explanation that closures can be functions assigned to variable. Though I once figured out how to assign a function to a pointer in C, 25 years ago, which was pretty much the same concept...